# How to get product of two columns for each row in table and order by result of two column desc postgre?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table with 6 to 7 columns in a Postgres database.

I have to get the product of two columns, `col1` and `col2`, for each row in the table and order by the result (descending order).

I have tried following things but haven't gotten the results I expected...

First:

```
SELECT SUM(col1 * col2) AS res
FROM   movies_b order by res desc;
```

But this gives me a single value for *all* rows.

Second:

```
SELECT col3, col4, col5, col6, SUM(col1 * col2) AS res 
FROM table 
ORDER BY res DESC
```

But this fails with the error:

> ERROR: column "table.col3"must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be
>   used in an aggregate function

I want to get all columns' values for each row and order the rows by the product of the two columns in descending order.

I hope I am clear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Where you're going wrong is trying to use aggregate functions like `SUM`. If you use `SUM` it will add up every row's result and return that single number (which you found out).

What you want doesn't involve actually aggregating any data from multiple rows. All you want to do is order by the result of `col1*col2`.

Here is an example query:

```
SELECT col1, col2, col3, col4, (col1*col2) AS product
FROM movies_b
ORDER BY (col1*col2) DESC
```

You can even delete that last part of the `SELECT` line if you want, just make sure you keep the `(col1*col2)` in the `ORDER BY` part.

SQL Fiddle is [up here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/d0d76/1).